# Is it possible to display another grid using a custom button similar to subgrid in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have subgrid in my grid and it works fine. Now, I am looking for something similar, but I would like to display the subgrid as a pop up grid using a custom button instead of displaying the subgrid inside the main grid, something similar to Add or Edit modal forms but display a grid instead of the modal form. Is it possible to do something like that? Please provide any examples if that is possible. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad if this could help!
Please refer: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

From the left navigation pane, Choose Advanced -> Master Detail.

There the sub grid is loaded just below the main grid for each row click on the main grid.
You can program the sub grid loaded on a modal flyout OR anyway you want.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sorry, I am not able to upvote since it requires reputation of 15. Also, can you explain how can I load the subgrid as a modal flyout? are you referring to the modal form as modal flyout?